# How to read in object files in C?

Tags: c, fgetc

Let's say there's an object file input.obj. In the terminal, if I do "cat input.obj," it returns some random characters like "???A?J." But when I "hexdump" it, it shows the values I want to read in into my program.

I read in this obj file into program.c, firstly by opening it using fopen and read byte by byte using fgetc. However, it is actually reading the contents as shown in "cat input.obj," whereas I want it to read the actual contents as in hexdump. Any ideas?

Code snippet (from poster's comment):

```
 char *filename; 
 FILE *f; 
 char c; 
 f = fopen(filename, "r"); 
 c = fgetc(f);
```

Comment: Show us the `fopen()` statement, because there are flags that specify whether the file to be opened is in binary or in text, which can break what you get out of the stream if you do not use the right mode.

Comment: Basically, please provide code.

Comment: You will need to use binary input; either `getc()` or `fread()` or one of their relatives.  You will need to understand the structure of the file to emulate `hexdump`.  That involves understanding ELF format on Linux, and different object file formats on other machines.  You'll need to look up the object file reading libraries on the different machines you're interested in.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think these "object files" have anything to do with compiled elf files. More likely they're just binary files the OP happens to call objects (correct me if I'm wrong, OP).

Comment: @Chris: You may be right, though `input.obj` might be a Windows object file. More seriously, `hexdump` probably doesn't interpret the object files as object files but as simple binary files, for which `fgetc()` is fine as long as the file is opened in binary mode (it matters on Windows; it doesn't on Unix, of course).  I was thinking of `objdump` instead of `hexdump` for no very clear reason.

Comment: A portion of my code: char *filename; FILE *f;
    char c;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
        c = fgetc(f);

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you need to print the integer representation of each byte to get what you want, not the byte itself. Try this:

```
char ch = ...; // Set ch to the value you read from the file
printf("%x", ch & 0xff);
```

The & 0xFF makes sure that the value is printed as 1 byte.

Comment: Since a `char` is always one byte in C, why mask it?

Comment: @AlexReynolds: `char` is promoted to `int` when passed through varargs. Also, `char` is often `signed` by default.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue which I had faced as well.
Surprisingly fopen and fgetc won't get the whole text file and will reach EOF without parsing the whole object file.

Use open() and read() system calls instead. You can check their syntax using man pages.

They give you the whole object file as seen when you do

$ hexdump -C 1_hello.o